# Using a 48 characters char[] for PROGMEM

Tags: led, atmega328, progmem

I am trying to create a charliplexed display of 6x8 LEDS using a Arduino Nano with the ATMega328p chip. Because of the limited storage I am trying to use PROGMEM. I did my research and found some usefull examples, but when I try to create a char[] of 48 charaters (0 = LED off, 1 = LED on), the monitor only shows a line filled with squares. Im not sure what this indicates, but when I limit the amount of characters to lets say 10, it works as expected. I made sure the buffer size matches the amount of max characters. What am I missing here?

I know it would be easier to use a multiplexer, but I prefer to find a working solution using progmem since this is a assignment where I would like to have my students find a solution to store the "LED data" for the whole alphabet without using external memory or a multiplexer chip. If this simply is not possible, I will look into using other hardware.

TIA!

This is the code I am using:

```
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
const char string_0[] PROGMEM = "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"; // "String 0" etc are strings to store - change to suit.
const char string_1[] PROGMEM = "String 1";
const char string_2[] PROGMEM = "String 2";
const char string_3[] PROGMEM = "String 3";
const char string_4[] PROGMEM = "String 4";
const char string_5[] PROGMEM = "String 5";


// Then set up a table to refer to your strings.

const char *const string_table[] PROGMEM = {string_0, string_1, string_2, string_3, string_4, string_5};

char buffer[48];  // make sure this is large enough for the largest string it must hold

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);  // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB
  Serial.println("OK");
}


void loop() {
  /* Using the string table in program memory requires the use of special functions to retrieve the data.
     The strcpy_P function copies a string from program space to a string in RAM ("buffer").
     Make sure your receiving string in RAM  is large enough to hold whatever
     you are retrieving from program space. */


  for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    strcpy_P(buffer, (char *)pgm_read_word(&(string_table[i])));  // Necessary casts and dereferencing, just copy.
    Serial.println(buffer);
    delay(500);
```

Comment: do you have place for terminating zero in `buffer`?

Comment: Obviously not. `char buffer[49];` will fix that issue. Also I wouldn't bother to place `string_table` in `PROGMEM` if you are not desperate to save 12 bytes of RAM.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue... Since I never worded with progmem before, I didnt know I needed to use an extra index for it. Thanks!

Eventually I will be adding every letter of the alphabet, including capitals and non capitals. And maybe if there is some more space, some symbols haha.

Comment: You could try strlcpy_P(buffer, ...pgm..., sizeof(buffer)). That is a extra 'l' as in Lima.